# How to add Google Keep API scope?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-keep

I am trying connecting to Google Keep API but i cannot add scopes in Google Cloud Console.

I have enabled Google Keep API in Library but still can't add scopes to access this API. I am getting this error:

> The following scope(s) were not added because they are invalid. Please
> update or remove these scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/keep
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/keep.readonly

[image: screen]

Comment: which product are you using and how do you try to add these scopes?

Comment: All actions were in the Google Cloud Platform interface 

1. Created a new Project
2. Created OAuth Client ID with Web application type and get Client ID and Client Secret
3. Enabled Google Keep API in Library
4. In the "OAuth consent screen" section, i enter the App name and Support email and try to add scopes using the interface. There i do not find scopes for Google Keep API in the list of scopes, so i try to enter them manually in textbox, but i cant pass the validation and dont know why. 
When i enabled others APIs in Library i see scopes for them in list of scopes and can add them

Answer (score 2):

I am running into the same issue. Upon further digging I found this explanation:

> This API is an enterprise-only API used to create and manage the Keep notes within your domain, ...

Which was found in the Google Keep API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/keep/api/reference/rest).

(Thanks to amanda-tarafa on 2021-09-03 found <strike>[here]</strike>[2](https://issueexplorer.com/issue/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/1930).
EDIT: the link is now dead.)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a reason and it's really disappointing...
Is there any update on the matter since 2021?
For anyone still trying to access Keep by code, this repo seems like a good alternative https://github.com/kiwiz/gkeepapi

Comment: the link to https://issueexplorer.com/issue/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/1930 is dead

Comment: recently [an enterprise user also has the problem of add Keep API scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76925716/3416774)