# How to add Google Keep API scopes in Google Cloud Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-keep

I am trying to connect to the Google Keep API using OAuth 2.0, but I cannot add the required scopes in the Google Cloud Console. I have enabled the Google Keep API in the Library section, but when I try to add the scopes in the OAuth consent screen section, I get this error:

The following scope(s) were not added because they are invalid. Please update or remove these scopes:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/keep

According to the [Google Keep API documentation](https://developers.google.com/keep/api/reference/rest/v1/notes/get), this scope is necessary to access the notes and lists in my Google account. However, it does not appear in the list of available scopes, and I cannot enter it manually.

How can I solve this problem? Is there any alternative way to access the Google Keep API without this scope? Or is this a bug in the Google Cloud Console or the Google Keep API?

P.S.: I'm an enterprise user if this is something relevant

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Being an Enterprise User is relevant.
As of today, Google Keep APIs are enterprise APIs and they need domain-wide delegation.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en#zippy=%2Cset-up-domain-wide-delegation-for-a-client.
A Domain Super Admin can authorize your application using Admin Console via
Menu > Security > Access and data control > API controls > Manage Domain Wide Delegation
You'll need OAuth Client ID and OAuth scopes.

Checkout this note from https://developers.google.com/keep/api/guides
[image]